# How do you install PrestaShop inside a Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, installation, prestashop

I'm trying to install Smashing Magazine's free e-commerce wordpress theme that uses PrestaShop and Wordpress together. I've been trying for about a day already and can't figure it out. Anyone willing to help?

this is the link to the file

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/26/free-prestashop-and-wordpress-e-commerce-theme-velvet-sky/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [these suggestions](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/74782/integration/solved_wordpress_integration__prestashoptowordpress_plugin_issue/) they are very similar to your problem. You should also install the Prestashop-to-Wordpress plugin and the PrestaShop module for WordPress. I think you have to pay for the PrestaShop module for WordPress though.

Answer (score 0):

It is two separate installs, 1 wp and 2 prestashop! The theme was designed to look the same so one can have both and user can navigate both but seems as they are on one platform, you can't install prestashop inside wordpress, you could possibly add the header & footer as well as a widget inside the blog or use iframe to view parts of it. They are two different platforms and to integrate both fully you would either have to create a module of some sort for prestashop or a plugin for wordpress in either case you would be using one or the other with both installed in your hosting account. If you want a shop in your blog or a blog in your shop the best way to do this would be to have a web designer create you a custom themes that look similar for both wordpress and prestashop, this would also be the case for any other shopping of blog platform. With that said both wordpress and prestashop offer solutions. With wordpress you can add plugins in order to sell products in your blog, with prestashop they offer various blog modules that you can install in your store, so you do have some options, I hope this helps sort it out for you, Good Day!